# Когда применять exists() ,isFile(), canRead() из класса File в Java

Tags: java, io

Имеет ли смысл такая проверка файла перед попыткой чтения из него?

```
File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);

if (inputFile.exists() && inputFile.isFile() && inputFile.canRead()) {...}
```

Может здесь что-то лишнее? Если я не ошибаюсь метод exists() вернёт false при отсутствии права записи в файл или если он скрытый. Еще мне кажется этот код затратным. Как лучше выполнить проверку файла перед считыванием данных из него?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методы `isFile` и `canRead` сами проверяют существование файла, поэтому предварительный `exists` не нужен. Но `canRead` довольно специфично себя ведёт, например, под Windows возвращает `true` для каталогов, поэтому сильно на него я бы не рассчитывал.

И ещё такой момент, что предварительная проверка не гарантирует, что тот же `FileInputStream` будет создан на этом файле. Обработку исключения придётся делать в любом случае. Во-первых, может быть специфика прав доступа. Во-вторых, файл могут успеть за это время удалить (очень маловероятно, но возможно). В-третьих, не гасить же исключение.

Поэтому возможна схема, что сперва сделать предварительную проверку при помощи `isFile`, в случае `false` можно, например, посмотреть при помощи `isDirectory`, не каталог ли это, уточнив сообщение об ошибке. Если существует файл, то открывать его, но с обработкой исключения. `exists` и `canRead` же в этом случае вообще не вызывать. Если уточнение сообщения об ошибке не нужно, то сразу открывать файл, отдав всё на откуп обработке исключения.